# Laravel deployment shared hosting subdomain

Tags: laravel, hosting, shared-hosting

Hi i spend few hours to make my website work on shared host but nothing happened(locally its OK),
Searched few topics and followed tutorials but cant fix the problem that cant load bootstrap and livewire components.

I followed the classic step that copy the public folder to the root of my subdomain and the other files are on separate folder inside the subdomain path like Laravel folder
I change the public/index.php and im getting something like [this](https://e-michanikos.netgen.gr)

as you can see the livewire and the bootstrap doesn't work.

Also i tried to let the folders as original and i path to public and the result is like [this](https://e-michanikos.netgen.gr/laravel/public/) and everything's work !

The index path that doesnt work css and livewire:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true));

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Check If Application Is Under Maintenance
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| If the application is maintenance / demo mode via the "down" command we
| will require this file so that any prerendered template can be shown
| instead of starting the framework, which could cause an exception.
|
*/

if (file_exists(__DIR__.'/../storage/framework/maintenance.php')) {
    require __DIR__.'/../storage/framework/maintenance.php';
}

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register The Auto Loader
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Composer provides a convenient, automatically generated class loader for
| this application. We just need to utilize it! We'll simply require it
| into the script here so we don't need to manually load our classes.
|
*/

require __DIR__.'/laravel/vendor/autoload.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Run The Application
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Once we have the application, we can handle the incoming request using
| the application's HTTP kernel. Then, we will send the response back
| to this client's browser, allowing them to enjoy our application.
|
*/

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/laravel/bootstrap/app.php';

$kernel = $app->make(Kernel::class);

$response = tap($kernel->handle(
    $request = Request::capture()
))->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

I know that i didnt put /../ because i get error doesn't recognize the path if i put that, maybe because is subdomain, and doesn't have public_html folder.
What cause that problem ? the path of bootstrap is correct..

Web.config :

```
<!--
    Rewrites requires Microsoft URL Rewrite Module for IIS
    Download: https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite
    Debug Help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules
-->
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^(.*)/$" ignoreCase="false" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="/{R:1}" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="Imported Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^" ignoreCase="false" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

htaccess :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Why are you using a Shared Host ? Do you even have SSH access ? The importan thing should be that Apache or Nginx document root is `LARAVEL_ROOT/public` and that's it, then everything should be in the root like `app`, `bootstrap`, `storage`, etc folders...

Comment: Because are vfm option instead of expensive vps with limited space, I have ssh access but I don't now what can I do to fix them

Comment: Are you using Apache or Nginx ? Could you share in your post the config file for your site ?

Comment: @matiaslauriti Im on Hostinger shared host and im using Apache, i uploaded  htaccess and web.config on post

Comment: I have no idea what hostinger has. If you are using Apache, can you share the virtual host that is on `/etc/apache2/sites-available`

Comment: I don't know what happened but today everything it's OK what happened? Maybe the cookies?

Comment: Oh wow, really strange... maybe the server got restarted and that reloaded some config that previously was not being taken into account, but cookies I don't think so.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Its late, but hopefully useful for future viewers

From the comments I could read you are using Hostinger,

Here is a quick work around,

In your hosting account > select

> Hosting Account > Domains > SubDomains

Enter the sub domain name and

> check the custom folder for subdomain

Enter the path of your project followed by the public dir of laravel

for eg,

```
/home/u796769252/public_html/<subdomain>/public
```

Voila,

you can now paste your laravel core files to suddomain and public folder files to the public folder.

I wrote a [blog](http://blog.tesmachino.com/laravel-application-in-hostinger-shared-hosting/) where I mentioned how to publish laravel application to shared hosting without editing the laravel core files.

Comment: Yes it worked, i faced again the same problem and i followed exact your instructions and finally Worked!
Thank you very much

Comment: Perfect! So simple. Thank you. Saved me hours.